# How to implement hierarchical multilevel datatable in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables, hierarchy

I am implementing multi level datatable without using any plugin or library. I want to implement based on javaScript, JQuery or angular js. I checked one below links,

> [Traverse all the Nodes of a JSON Object Tree with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722668/traverse-all-the-nodes-of-a-json-object-tree-with-javascript)
>
> [nested table using ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062032/nested-table-using-ng-repeat)

But my json structure is different from above link.

I need to display my JSON in Tree Structure UI. I don't hard code level in html. All level should be handle by javascript.

I have implemented jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/0n9fmawb/40/

**JSON STRUCTURE**

```
[  {
      Home:{
                "checkbox_view":true,
                "checkbox_edit":false,
                "checkbox_delete":true
      }
   },
   {  
      "watchColorWorld":{  
         "local":{  
            "app-local-black":{
             "checkbox_view":true,
             "checkbox_edit":true,
             "checkbox_delete":true
            }

         },
         "global":{  
           "app-global-red":{            
             "checkbox_view":true,
             "checkbox_edit":true,
             "checkbox_delete":true
            }

         },
         "world":{  
            "app-world-green":{
             "checkbox_view":true,
             "checkbox_edit":true,
             "checkbox_delete":true
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "systemMgmt":{  
            "checkbox_view":true,
             "checkbox_edit":true,
             "checkbox_delete":true
      }
   },
   {  
      "rules":{  
         "Rule1":{  
            "rule2":{
              "rule3":{  
                   "checkbox_view":true,
                   "checkbox_edit":true,
                   "checkbox_delete":true
            }
         }
         }

      }
   }
]
```

**Expacted Output**
[image]

You answer valuable for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not really clear, you need to display your JSON in Tree Structure UI?

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher thanks for the comment. Yes, I have to display my json in tree structure IN UI.

Comment: then maybe you can try something like [this component](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree)

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher Thanks for the good communication. I don't want to use any external big library.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734341/angular-checkboxes-in-tree-view) might help.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thanks for the comment. But mentioned code is not working in the jsfillde link.

Comment: You should try it in a new fiddle and debug it yourself. The OP of that post accepted the linked answer so it is likely to be a working solution.

Comment: I added filddle. http://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/0n9fmawb/33/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of accomplishing this with vanilla Javascript would be a modified depth first traversal of an object:

```js
function renderJSON(json) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');

  const stack = [{
    node: json,
    name: 'root',
    parentEl: wrapper
  }];

  while (stack.length > 0) {
    let current = stack.pop();
    let currentObj = current.node;
    let currentParentEl = current.parentEl;

    let level = document.createElement('div');

    level.classList.add('level');
    level.textContent = current.name + ': ';

    if (currentObj.renderContent) {
      // render custom html content
      currentObj.renderContent(level);
    } else if (!(currentObj instanceof Object)) {
      level.textContent += currentObj;
    }

    currentParentEl.append(level);

    if (currentObj instanceof Object) {
      let keys = Object.keys(currentObj);

      if (!currentObj.skipChildren) {
        // push in reverse to preserve key order
        for (let i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          let key = keys[i];
          let node = currentObj[key];

          stack.push({
            node: node,
            name: key,
            parentEl: level
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return wrapper;
}

// Example Use Case:
const Permissions = function Permissions() {
  this.skipChildren = true;
  this.view = false;
  this.edit = false;
  this.delete = false;
};
Permissions.prototype = {
  renderContent(el) {
    const fields = ['view', 'edit', 'delete'];

    for (let field of fields) {
      const label = document.createElement('label');
      label.textContent = field;

      const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
      checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
      checkbox.checked = this[field];

      label.appendChild(checkbox);
      el.appendChild(label);
    }
  }
};

const rendered = renderJSON({
  element1: {
    a: 4,
    b: 6,
    c: 24,
    element1a: {
      a: 'hello'
    }
  },
  element2: {
    a: 'abc',
    permissions: new Permissions()
  },
  element3: ["first", "second", "third"]
});

document.body.append(rendered);
```

```css
.level {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

There's a lot of different ways you could branch off of this code depending on your needs. Since you're given a JSON string to begin with, you'll need to find some way to convert that into a Javascript object that will produce the result you want.